# What does canvas.translate do?

Tags: android, android-canvas

An example can be found here [compass.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Compass.html).
[Api here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#translate%28float,%20float%29)

Comment: To anyone still checking this in the future, translate will only move the canvas coordinates, not anything you drew on it. So translate first, draw next :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Translate - Basically do what it says. Just translate the canvas using x,y. If you want to draw two objects and the one is just translation of the other e.g x2 = x1 + 50 for each point . You don't have to make all your calculations again for the second object but you can just translate the canvas and draw again the same object. I hope this [example](http://bestsiteinthemultiverse.com/2008/11/android-graphics-example/) will help you.

Comment: I still don't understand what it does. Could you explain why they do the translate, draw and then undo the translate?

Comment: Ok image you have a canvas and you want to draw 2 trees on it and one bird which is above the first tree. The trees have the same y coordinate but different x (let's say for example 50 inches). So what are you going to do ? .... continue

Comment: You'll draw the first three then you'll move your canvas 50 inches to the right ( which is what canvas.translate do ) and will draw the second tree. In order to restore the original position of the canvas you'll move it again 50 inches but this time to the left. And now when you draw the bird it'll be above the first tree, if you don't restore the canvas original state all object that you draw after the translation will be translated to - in our example the bird will be drawn above the second tree

Comment: You don't have to. The first time you have to deal with such stuff is little confusing but once you get used to it things are getting simpler.

Comment: couldn't agreed more, the explanation is killing me! Nice work .

Comment: Maybe a stupid noob question, however can you get the translate to draw smoothly so pixerl by pixel, rather than jump to the new position?

Answer (score 100):

Even when I first answered this question a few years ago, I didn't really understand how `Canvas` transforms (like `translate`, `rotate`, etc.) worked. I used to think that `translate` moved the thing that you were drawing. Actually, `translate` moves the entire coordinate system. This has the desired effect of also moving the thing you are drawing.

On your screen it looks like you are moving the drawing:

[image: Android Canvas.translate() method]

What is actually happening is you are moving the coordinate system to a new place on the canvas:

[image]

I draw the tree first at `(0,0)`. Then I translate the origin of the coordinate system to some other spot on the canvas. Then I draw the tree again at `(0,0)`. This way my drawing code doesn't have to change anything at all. Only the coordinate system changes.

Normally `(0,0)` is at the top left of your view. Doing `Canvas.translate` moves it to some other part of your view.

## Saving and Restoring the Coordinate System

You can do `save()` and `restore()` to get back to your original coordinate system.

```
// draw the tree the first time
canvas.drawBitmap(tree, 0, 0, mPaint);

// draw the tree the second time
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(dx, dy); // dx = change in x, dy = change in y
canvas.drawBitmap(tree, 0, 0, mPaint); // draw still thinks it is at (0,0)
canvas.restore(); // undo the translate
```

When you `restore`, the drawing is already on the canvas. Restoring doesn't change that. It just moves the coordinate system back to wherever it was when you saved it.

## Why Translate

Note that you could achieve the same affect by changing the x,y coordinates of the draw method:

```
// draw the tree the first time
canvas.drawBitmap(tree, x, y, mPaint);

// update the x,y coordinates
x += dx;
y += dy;

// draw the tree the second time
canvas.drawBitmap(tree, x, y, mPaint);
```

This might be more intuitive coming from a math background. However, when you are translating, rotating, and scaling your image, it is often much easy to keep your drawing logic the same and just transform the canvas. Recalculating `x` and `y` for every draw could be very expensive.

Comment: I actually wanted to know what save(), translate() and restore() all did. And this answers it.

Answer (score 54):

### Imagine it's a Print Head.

The easiest way to explain this is to imagine it is the print head of an inkjet or 2D printer.

`translate` basically *"moves"* the print head along the X and Y axes the number of pixels that you tell it to.

The resulting position becomes the new *"origin"* (0,0).

Now that we understand that, let's make a simple face by doing the following:

**Starting Origin:**

```
x
```

*The `x` will (roughly) represent where the origin (or print head) is.*

**Draw a rectangle for the left eye:**

```
canvas.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 10, paint);

x__
|__|
```

*Note: The "origin" has not changed, it is still at the top left of this rectangle.*

**Move "origin" right by 20 points:**

```
canvas.translate(20, 0)

 __    x    
|__|
```

**Draw the right eye using the *exact same* rectangle command:**

```
canvas.drawRect(10, 10, 10, 10, paint);

 __    x__
|__|   |__|
```

**Move "origin" back to the original X position and move it down on the Y axis:**

```
canvas.translate(-20, 20) // Positive numbers for the second param is "down" on the y-axis.

 __     __
|__|   |__|

x
```

**And draw a mouth to finish it off:**

```
canvas.drawLine( 0, 0, 30, 0, paint ); 
 __     __
|__|   |__|

x___________
```

**Now just move the "origin" down 20 points to showcase our masterpiece:**

```
canvas.translate(0, 20)
 __     __
|__|   |__|

___________

x
```

*Not perfectly to scale as there's only so much you can do with a monospace font. :)*

Comment: This is the best explanation by far, now after few drawings, it gets a bit complicated. Is there a way to reset to origin?

Comment: @Lamar Thanks. Not sure if there's a built in method but you could keep track of it manually so that every time you use translate, you update your local variable to show "how far away you are from the starting point". And then if you want to go back to that original starting point, you could just us a translate to reverse those movements.

Comment: Yes that's what I ended up doing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I thought your name was Joshua **Printer**

Comment: @mallaudin Ha! I get that a lot, but it seems funnier here given what this answer. Would explain my bias towards _print_ heads.

Comment: Yup. I first read your answer and suddenly thought is it the Printer. Great answer btw.

Comment: point me out if I am wrong, but drawRect takes 2 coordinates, the top left and bottom right, so it should be canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 10, 10, paint);

Comment: @BabyishTank Did you read the docs?: `public void drawRect (float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint)` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawRect(float,%2520float,%2520float,%2520float,%2520android.graphics.Paint)

Answer (score 0):

it will change the position of your canvaz(except scale) either x or y
if we translate & scale then it is transformation in general terminology